# How to go back to prelude> in ghci

Tags: haskell

When I `:load` a Haskell script into GHCi, it changes the prompt from `Prelude>` to `*Main>`. After I'm done with this script, how can I go back to the `Prelude>` prompt? There seems to be no documentation regarding this.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Try using the `:m` command. It should unload all the modules.

This is short for `:module` which sets the current context. You can also load arbitrary modules this way:

```
Prelude> :m Data.List Control.Applicative
Prelude Data.List Control.Applicative> :m
Prelude>
```

Answer (score 16):

Adding to the answer by @Tikhon Jelvis.

Apparently you can choose to unload modules using the syntax `:m -<module>`. As in:

```
Prelude> import Numeric
Prelude Numeric> :m -Numeric
Prelude> :m +Numeric
Prelude Numeric>
```

Source: [[Haskell] Import/unimport a module into ghci](http://kuniganotas.wordpress.com/2012/09/08/haskell-importunimport-a-module-into-ghci/)

Answer (score 0):

You can

1. Change directory via `:cd /new/directory`
2. Load another file/module. It causes the preceding module to unload.

See the definition of :cd/:load in https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.6/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-commands.html